# Using lme4 correctly for a nested mixed model

Tags: r, mixed-model, random-effects-model, lme4-nlme, nested-data

I'm trying to create a nested model in lme4 and would like feedback on whether I've understood its use correctly.

Every individual (n = 144) had two proteins measured after 0, 12 and 72 hours. At each timepoint, the protein was measured twice. It's an observational study where the samples are from different medical centers. A sample of the data looks like this:

`ID           Sex  Center    Age  Time Rep Pentraxin3          IL6
1    10151   Male       1    56      0   1       0.23          0.98
2    10151   Male       1    56      0   2       0.29          1.05
3    10151   Male       1    56     12   1       1.26          1.18
4    10151   Male       1    56     12   2       1.48          1.23
5    10151   Male       1    56     72   1       0.40          1.86
6    10151   Male       1    56     72   2       0.49          2.13
7    10201 Female       3    59      0   1       0.79          0.50
8    10201 Female       3    59      0   2       1.01          0.51
9    10201 Female       3    59     12   1         NA          2.46
10   10201 Female       3    59     12   2         NA          2.46
11   10201 Female       3    59     72   1         NA          1.62
12   10201 Female       3    59     72   2         NA          1.44`

What I would like to do is model the effect of Pentraxin3 on IL6 (IL6 ~ Pentraxin3) and take into account the following random effects, where the code next to each statement is what I think is the lme4 code for that particular random effect:

1. There can be correlations between the repeated measures at each time point.
   (1|Time/Rep)

   2. There can be correlations between the biomarker values measured at different time points within each individual. 
      (1|ID/Time)
   3. There can be correlations between individuals within the same center. (1|Center)
   4. There are different slopes between individuals in the change of Pentraxin3 over time. (Pentraxin3 - 1 | ID/Time)

This is the model including fixed effects and random effects:

```
m6 <- lmer(IL6 ~ Sex + Pentraxin3 + Age + (1|Center) + (1|ID/Time) + (1|Time/Rep) + (Pentraxin3 - 1|ID/Time), data = d1)`
```

Is this correct? Should "Time" be a fixed effect?

`

Comment: How big is your sample? Remember that the most coherent random effects structure is not necessarily the one that can be successfully estimated by your data.

Comment: 144 individuals, thank you, I forgot to mention that in the question.

Comment: I am not sure what the (1|ID/Time) is specifying in the model or if that formulation is even supported. Do you mean to have (Time|ID) to specify random intercept and random slope? The following documentation indicates that you do not need to specify random effects differently in lme4 than you would have to specify crossed effects:
http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/book/Ch2.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I was hoping (1|ID/Time) would give me a random intercept accounting for the correlation between measures at different timepoints within the same individual. If (Time|ID) gives a random slope between individuals in their measures over time, than that would fulfill what I thought (Pentraxin3 - 1|ID/Time) would do.